# Sorting an array, even numbers first, using recursive method. (not working)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

/*
Write a short recursive Java method that rearranges an array of integer values so
that all the even values appear before all the odd values.
 */

When I use isEven() on an array, and then print the array in the main method, it prints the original array rather than a sorted array.

I think I'm messing up on the passing primitive variables by value... Other than that, I really don't understand why the recursion isn't working.

Thanks!

```
static int isEven(int[] array, int position)
{ 
    if(array[position]%2 == 0)
    {
        return array[position];
    }
    else
    {
        int j = position;
        int x = isEven(array, position++);
        array[position] = array[j];
        array[j] = x;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `position++` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: ok, position holds an int...so the int value is passed...and I'm hoping that with each call isEven()....position is incremented (now I'm realizing this could have led to an infinite recursion, since there's no limit on position) ...and now I'm extra confused.

Comment: it is!! thanks dambros...honestly I feel really discouraged that I wasn't able to solve this on my own. Recursion is horrible. My code doesn't even look a bit similar to the answer.

Comment: I was trying your code here. The line isEven(array, position++); is triggering an infinite loop as position seen to be passed before incremented.